# How, using .NET RegEx, do I parse an HTML file and find 1. External links. 2. Internal links

Tags: c#, regex, web-crawler

I am writing a program that will help me find out sites are my competitors linking to.

In order to do that, I am writing a program that will parse an HTML file, and will produce 2 lists: internal links and external links.

I will use the internal links to further crawl the website, and the external links are actually what I am looking for.

How, using .NET RegEx, do I parse an HTML file and find 1. External links. 2. Internal links.

Thanks in advance,
Eytan Levit.

Edit: In response to the question - no - I am not bound to regex, i can use any other ideas.

Comment: are you bound to RegEx, or third-party DOM-parsing libs can be used too ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression for this.

Use something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) which is specifically designed for parsing HTML. (There's even an example on their CodePlex homepage which finds all links in a page.)

Comment: Is it efficient?(i mean one day i do plan to turn my application into a real web spider)

Comment: +1 for HTML Agility Pack, it's very usefull library for processing HTML

@Eytan Levit: yes, I use this library in few projects with no problems

Answer (score 0):

i had used Regex for Html parsing it is really fast but now there are better options that will reduce the development cost.

Try [Linq To Html](http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2008/04/25/querying-html-with-linq-to-xml.aspx) it's good, Beth has a great post about it that can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2008/04/25/querying-html-with-linq-to-xml.aspx)